# Control to show text based on where mouse pointer is

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

How do i get this? Which control shows some text when i keep the mouse cursor there for a while?

[image]

Edit: I have a timeline in my program. I want the tooltip to show the time value in milliseconds at the point where the mouse cursor is... Is it possible to have a flexible tooltip over a control?

Comment: Yes you can show the value hovered by the mouse cursor. You have to do some calculation to make it happens.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for the [ToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) control.

---

Refer to the following:

[Tooltip in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/2345/)

[image: Normal Tooltip]

[image: Balloon Tooltip]

Answer (score 2):

`ToolTip` is the magic word. Have a look at the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for

[How To Add ToolTips To Controls On A Windows Form](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/tooltips.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display some text over the print button named "printBtn",
Then add the event mouse hover as below

```
printBtn.MouseHover += new EventHandler(printBtn_MouseHover);
```

Then, use the following code to display the text when the mouse is over the print button

```
void printBtn_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
   tip.SetToolTip(printBtn, "Click to print");
}
```